# read lines in a file in groovy and split them to find a string

Tags: groovy

I have a file with the following content :

```
aws_elb.web-elb
aws_autoscaling_group.web-asg
aws_launch_configuration.web-lc
```

*This file can get bigger. I want to iterate over every lines and split them on "." and then check the first part . As soon as I find "aws_autoscaling_group" , I want to exit out of loop and return true.*

Whats the most groovy way of doing it ?

Comment: Is that a property file? Can't you just use file content contains the string and return true? May be more details would help better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just read file and check if it contains 'aws_autoscaling_group'

```
def fileContents = new File('/file/path').text
def result = fileContents.contains('aws_autoscaling_group.') ? true : false
println result
```

Comment: No need for a ternary.  Why evaluate with contains, which returns true/false, then use a ternary to return true/false?  If true return true/if false return false?
Simply (it IS Groovy, after all) 
`println new File('/file/path')?.text?.contains('aws_autoscaling_group.')`